# How can I override **partially** a third-party template?

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to override a template from third-party bundle by following one of the Symfony's built-in conventions. The [Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html) talks about them:

> To override the bundle template, just copy `index.html.twig` template from the bundle to `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/index.html.twig` (the `app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle` directory won't exist, so you'll need to create it). You're now free to customize the template.
>
> You can also override templates from within a bundle by using bundle inheritance. For more information, see [How to Use Bundle Inheritance to Override Parts of a Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html).

While this approach may work, it can be overly complicated if you only need to override a small portion of the template (e.g. some blocks). Additionally, if the third-party bundle updates its own template, your version of the template may become outdated and require updates to stay current with the latest changes.

This is what I've tried to do without success:

```
{# app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '@AcmeBlog/Blog/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My Default Title{% endblock %}
```

The above code doesn't work. It breaks after reaching the maximum execution time when I've accessed this page and the clear cache command never ends.

Why it doesn't works and how to achieve it without copying the entire parent template from the third-party bundle?

---

Related issues and pull-requests without workaround:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1966 (2011)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/2202 (2011)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/752 (2011) | [Unrelated](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/inheritance.html).
- https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1334 (2014)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15755 (2015)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17054 (2015)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17407 (2016)
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17557 (2016)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why it doesn't works?
>
> ```
> {# app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/layout.html.twig #}
> {% extends '@AcmeBlog/Blog/layout.html.twig' %}
>
> {% block title %}My Default Title{% endblock %}
> ```

The reason comes from Twig's paths and namespaces auto-configuration between bundles, their children and Symfony's path convention. By default `Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle` assign the same Twig's namespace (`AcmeBlog`) for all paths, following this order:

```
# config.yml
twig:
    paths:
        # Auto-configuration behind the scenes for TwigBundle extension:

        # (1st) if AcmeBlogChildBundle has as parent to AcmeBlogBundle
        'src/AcmeBlogChildBundle/Resources/views': AcmeBlog 

        # (2nd) Path to override bundles (Symfony's convention)
        'app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views':      AcmeBlog 

        # (3rd) third-party bundle
        'vendor/acme/blog-bundle/Resources/views': AcmeBlog
```

That means, if you need to render the `@AcmeBlog/Blog/layout.html.twig` template, Twig try to find it in all paths (in the order has been defined) whose namespace matches `AcmeBlog`.

So to override it, you had to create this template (`/Blog/layout.html.twig`) in (1st) or (2nd) paths. But, if you're extending from `@AcmeBlog/Blog/layout.html.twig` at the same time (thinking about extends from the original template) then Twig performs the same previous procedure, causing a circular template reference (infinite loop) and never reach the (3rd) path.

> How to achieve it without copy the entire parent template from the third-party bundle?

**Symfony's built-in workaround**

Let's define a different Twig's namespace for this third-party bundle in `twig` paths configuration:

```
# config.yml
twig:
    paths:
        # (4th) third-party bundle alias.
        # The path can be relative to project or real path
        vendor/acme/blog-bundle/Resources/views: AcmeBlogOriginal
```

Later, use the namespace alias to avoid circular reference when you're overriding a third-party template that extends from the original:

```
{# app/Resources/AcmeBlogBundle/views/Blog/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '@AcmeBlogOriginal/Blog/layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}My Default Title{% endblock %}
```

Thus, you're able to override blocks instead the whole template. Even should work out-of-the-box as it's about Twig's paths only.

---

**Since Symfony 3.4 this issue has been solved as built-in feature.**
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-improved-the-overriding-of-templates#overriding-and-extending-templates

Comment: Worth noting that with Symfony 4.1 or above you can reference the parent using @! without the need to define it as an extra twig path: https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#templates